# Find integral of $1/z^2$ from $-4i$ to $4i$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find integral of $1/z^2$ from $-4i$ to $4i$ and the path given is "any contour that doesn't pass through the origin". Now I understand that the book wants me to use the fundamental theorem of complex integral because I am on the section about path independence. But the theorem itself states that a function is only path independent if it's smoothly connected, but $0$ is not defined so the function is multiply connected no? So can we still assume path independence here?

Comment: Path independence comes from the existence of an antiderivative, for which simple connectedness of the domain is sufficient, but not necessary. I'm sure you can find an antiderivative of $1/z^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you integrated along a closed circular path that enclosed the origin, the result would be zero, so as long as you avoid the origin, the integral is path independent:

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^2}=0,$$ where $C$ is any closed curve whose interior may or may not contain the origin, but does not pass through the origin.

Contrast this with $$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z}=\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
&2\pi i, & C \text{ surrounds the origin} \\ 
&0, & C \text{ does not surround the origin}
\end{aligned} 
\right.$$

The function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}$ has a primitive $F(z)=-\frac{1}{z}$,

so $$\int_{z_1}^{z_2} \frac{dz}{z^2}  = \left. -\frac{1}{z}\right|_{z_1}^{z^2} = \frac{1}{z_1} - \frac{1}{z_2}. $$

$$\int_{-4i}^{4i} \frac{dz}{z^2} = \frac{i}{4} - \left(-\frac{i}{4}\right)=\frac{i}{2}.$$

Comment: Your statement, " as long as you avoid the origin, the integral is path independent" seems correct for 1/z^2 , but not for 1/z.. For 1/z, the line integral from -1 to 1 gives different value for different paths. Why is this the case? I think the reason might have something to do with the fact that the log function is not defined on the negative real axis.

Comment: That is (mostly) right.  We have to define a branch for the logarithm, the negative real axis will do.  The function $1/z$ does not have a primitive in any region that contains the origin.  If we always "traveled from $-4i$ to $4i$" keeping the origin to our left, then yes, those paths result in the same integral for $1/z$ because we can define the branch to be the negative real axis (as you say) and the logarithm is a well defined primitive in a region containing these paths.